# How to do proper inheritance in Elm?

Tags: inheritance, functional-programming, elm

I'm making a todo list that can have items of type A or type B. So I made a type `Item` that is either `A` or `B`. The model holds a list of `ItemModel` and an integer that we use to assign a id to each todo-item.

```
module Feed where

import A
import B

-- MODEL

type Item = A | B
type ItemModel = A.Model | B.Model

type alias Id = Int

type alias Model = 
    { todo : List (Id, ItemModel)
    , nextCount : Id}

init : Model
init = Model [] 0
```

The function below is used to update an `ItemModel` in the model by looking it up by using its `Id`.

```
updateItem : (ItemModel -> ItemModel) -> Id -> Model -> Model
updateItem f id model =
  let test (id', x) = (id', if id == id' then f x else x)
  in Model (List.map test model.todo) model.nextCount
```

The trouble starts here. I don't know how I can use the update function of the Item that has a action invoked. `Item.update` doesn't work because it doesn't exist.

```
-- UPDATE

type Action = SubAction Id Item.Action

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    SubAction id action ->
      updateItem (Item.update action) id model
```

I'm also having trouble to display my list, I know `Item.view` doesn't work but it's to illustrate my thinking. The code works if f.e. I use `A.view` and have `todo : List (Id, A.Model)` but I want it to work for `A` and `B`. How do I tackle this?

```
-- VIEW

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  let view' (id, x) = Item.view (Signal.forwardTo address <| SubAction id) x
      lstTodo = List.map view' model.todo
  in Html.div [] lstTodo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, instead of `List (Id, ItemModel)` better use [`Dict`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Dict).

Then just pattern match (code is untested):

```
type Item = ItemA A.Model | ItemB B.Model
type Action = SubActionA Id A.Action | SubActionB Id B.Action | ...

updateA : A.Action -> Item -> Item
updateA action model = case model of
  ItemA model -> ... -- we have an A item here, do something
  Nothing -> ... -- there's a B item here, app logic must be wrong somewhere

updateB : B.Action -> Item -> Item
updateB action model = case model of
  ItemB model -> ... -- we have a B item here, do something
  Nothing -> ... -- there's an A item here, app logic must be wrong somewhere

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    SubActionA id action -> { model | todo = Dict.update id (Maybe.map (updateA action)) model.todo }
    SubActionB id action -> { model | todo = Dict.update id (Maybe.map (updateB action)) model.todo }
```

`updateA/B action` are curried here - so the type is `ItemModel -> ItemModel`.

Also note that `Maybe.map` maps a function `a -> b` to `Maybe a -> Maybe b` - exactly what [`Dict.update`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Dict#update) expects!

Similarly in the view:

```
case model of
  ItemA model -> A.view model
  ItemB model -> B.view model
```

For further reference - read [this](http://elm-lang.org/guide/model-the-problem) and especially the section about tagged unions.

Comment: Looks very promising but what do you have for `type Action = ...` ? It cannot be `SubAction Id Item.Action` so what should it be?

Comment: @Stanko: `type Action = SubActionA Id A.Action | SubActionB Id B.Action | ...`

Comment: @Stanko: I recommend reading the Elm Architecture Tutorial. Specifically [the counter pair example](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/#example-2-a-pair-of-counters).

Comment: `type Action = SubActionA Id A.Action | SubActionB Id B.Action` won't work because in your `updateItem`you expect a `SubAction`

Comment: @Stanko: see edits. I've split the `updateItem` function into 2 separate functions for further clarity.